# Deleting consecutive points if one of the points is in a field

Tags: ms-word, field

I write texts that I can print in an anonymised version. I do this using field codes that look like this:

*Ask Mister { IF { DOCPROPERTY Anonymous } = "N" "Tucker" "T." }*

Which in the anonymized text version would look like this:

*Ask Mister T.*

The problem is that if the anonymous code comes at the end of the sentence, I get double points:

*Ask Mister T..*

Each sentence can only have one dot at the end. So I want to delete the first one of the doubles in the version shown, i.e. the one the field code shows, preferably without changing the field code.

I can do this manually, by simply positioning the cursor after the *T* and deleting the first dot. The advantage is that I only have to refresh the field to undo it.

But I would like to have this done automatically, either by a search and replace, or by a macro.

Unfortunately, I'm getting nowhere. I cannot even find the double points using the search function. (Search *..* returns no hits). Other tricks like *^d.* or *^21.* do not work either.

No doubt one of you will come up with an easy way to do this.

Thanks a lot

Willem

Comment: So why do you have 'T.' in the field code instead of just 'T'?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question, Macropod! The reason I put a period after the abbreviation is because the official spelling rules tell me to, and I'd like to follow them. If the sentence does not end with the abbreviated name, the period must be there (example: _I asked Mister T. to do this._).

I have to say that I'm not sure what the best approach would be. I'm open to hearing a better one if you think of one.

Regards
Willem

Comment: So use two versions of the field - one with the period for mid-sentence and one without it for end-sentence.

Comment: Not a bad idea, Macropod. In an attempt to keep things simple for the user (myself), I am starting to think in a different direction: building a macro to save a copy as pdf, with the fields unlinked and the double dots removed from the then plain text. I'll do an effort to achieve that and will close this question.

Many thanks

Willem